# integer/real based classification at output layer?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Normally you would use softmax activation at the output layer if you have multiple-dependent classes and sigmoid if you have independent-classes (with one-hot encoding). By using multiple neurons , one per class.

How would you classify on a single neuron with integer/real value, where every value means a different class.

F.e. let say we pass at the input a number (based on vocabulary) which encodes a word and get at the output another number (signifying a word from vocabulary).

What would be the output layer configuration ? how would you that ?

---

when I test the following network on different arithmetic operations it seems to work ! Where I use arithmetic operation to simulate a categorical-in-out relation.

The question is will it preserve its behavior when mixed with category data, I mean in a mixed input data scenario, where this one is a branch of the full NN !?

```
class Arithmetic:

    def tt_data(self, ins=[np.random.randint(100) for _ in xrange(500)], outs=lambda x: x / 3):
        self.ins = np.array(ins)
        self.outs = np.array([ outs(i) for i in self.ins])
        self.in_size = 1
        self.out_size = 1
        return ( self.ins, self.outs )


    def build_model(self, ins=None, outs=None) :
        if isinstance(ins,tuple) : ins, outs = ins
        if ins is None : ins = self.ins
        if outs is None : outs = self.outs

        inputs = Input(shape=(self.in_size,))
        x = Dense(3,activation='relu')(inputs)
        x = Dense(3,activation='relu')(x)
        outputs = Dense(self.out_size,activation='linear')(x)
        self.model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
        self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy','mae'])
        print self.model.summary()
        self.history = self.model.fit(self.ins, self.outs, batch_size=10, epochs=200, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
        self.score = self.model.evaluate(ins, outs, verbose=1)
        print self.score
```

```
 In [29]: a.build_model(a.tt_data())               
 In [26]: a.model.predict(list(xrange(200,301,10)))
```